# Drupal 7 Views url translated alias with contextual filter

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I want to translate the url of my view. So I've made a translated alias for it. But when I add a contextual filter I get a 404 error.

For example: I've a view with the url `example.com/overview` with alias `example.com/overzicht` this works. This works also `example.com/overview/[category]`, but this doesn't work: `example.com/overzicht/[category]`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmm... that should work :) Although I don't have an environment to test now. You've done it the right way as http://www.bariswanschers.com/blog/translating-views-paths-drupal ie. Seems like an old sandbox tries to solve the problem but it feels that should have been solved by now http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-yusupov-1178106/tree/aliasarg.module. Some discussion https://www.drupal.org/node/504616#comment-1752596

Comment: you also can write some code to do that , if you are familiar with drupal coding I can guide you how to solve this problem using hook_views_query_alter() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution for my problem, after a couple of hours :).

It was solved after installing the [Extended Path Aliases](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt) module.

Answer (score 0):

The "[Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto)" module also does the trick (and has an official D8 version as well).